# ¿Como se activar un listener javascript para un botón enviar?

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title></title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">

  </style>
       <script type="text/javascript">


      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <form>
         <label>Nombre categoría</label><br>
         <input type="text" id="nombre"><br>
         <label>Descripción</label><br>
         <textarea id="descripcion"></textarea><br>
         <input type="button" id="alta">
      </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Tengo que introducir código javascript necesario para activar el listener del botón y realizar la llamada AJAX al servicio php.

Alguien tiene idea de como se hace?

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado?, obteniendo el botón por su id y haciendo uso de `addEventListener` lo consigues

Comment: Sí, realmente lo que tienes que hacer en el Js es document.getElementById('').addEventListener('click', e => {}); Trata de investigar un poco

Answer (score 0):

Yo siempre lo hago con

```
element.addEventListener('click',evt =>{...})
```

Aunque deberias de tomar en consideracion utilizar

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

en lugar del input, es mucho mas facil de controlar